# MSAL with Azure AD B2C and Single Sign On

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm working on a system with a few Angular 4 SPAs each talking to a separate Asp.NET Core 2.0 WebAPI.

Azure AD B2C is being used as the identity service for each SPA/API, and MSAL.js as part of our Angular SPAs.

We want to support Single Sign-on to prevent the user needing to re-enter credentials when switching from one SPA to another.

Is it possible to get single sign-on behavior using msal.js v0.1.7?

Comment: What do you expect the user experience to be when users move from the first SPA to the second one? Are they already signed in to the second one?

Comment: To be silently authenticated using the JWT from their initial login (e.g. not to have to re-enter their username and password).

Answer (score -1):

SSO with MSAL.js is possible. For browser-based apps you achieve SSO through cookies/sessions rather than tokens/token management. Please refer to the [Github library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js).  MSAL.js allows you to use acquireTokenSilent() to use a valid cookie via hidden iframe.

That said, the recommended way to do this is by using Azure [KMSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-kmsi-custom) with custom policies. This is because browser-based applications don't always keep users logged in and things like password changes can invalidate a user session.

Comment: Thanks - could you point me in the direction of the sample on the MSAL github page that demonstrates the use of SSO?

Comment: It is a library and not really a sample. There isn't a fully-fledged sample out there for this currently.