# Single SignOn with MSAL js on client and OWIN on serverside

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

I'm working on a setup with multiple .NET web applications which use the Microsoft.Owin NuGet packages aswell as OpenIdConnect for integration with Azure B2C AD. This enables Single SignOn (SSO) between all of these applications.

I want to include my Angular SPA in the SSO setup, such that if I signin to any of the .NET web applications and navigate to my SPA, I will also be signed into the SPA.

This almost sounds like an identical issue: [MSAL with Azure AD B2C and Single Sign On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242142/msal-with-azure-ad-b2c-and-single-sign-on) however, my system contains multiple .NET web applications.

Is that possible with MSAL.js? And if so, please add a link to an example if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can try to acquire tokens with the MSAL.js functions and see if the invisible iframe requests finish successfully. I'm not sure if it can acquire id tokens that way though.. If it cannot, then the redirect is necessary.

Comment: @juunas Do you mean that I should try to call acquireTokenSilent without calling login first?

Comment: Using logging, I can verify that Msal.UserAgentApplication.getUser() returns NULL.

Is there any way to handle this? Either an alternative way of signing in users in the Web application such that it is recognized by MSAL or an alternative way of fetching the user in MSAL js?

This code signs in users in the web application:

    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() {RedirectUri = Routes.RedirectAfterLogin(policy, returnUrl) }, policy);

Comment: If the silent acquire fails, then MSAL does not support that. You should add an issue on the MSAL.JS repository for that, unless there already is one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this [Github sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) that I left on the other question? SSO with MSAL.js should be possible. For browser-based apps you achieve SSO through cookies/sessions rather than tokens/token management.  MSAL.js allows you to use acquireTokenSilent() to use a valid cookie via hidden iframe.

The recommended method, however, is through Azure KMSI with custom policies.

Comment: Thanks. I have not been able to find any examples on SSO on the Github page you linked, so I also created an issue on their page a month ago.
Can you point me in the direction of the SSO example?

Comment: Hos, did you find any solution related to this problem ?