# How to get a Single Sign On with Blazor WebAssembly and Azure ADB2C MSAL Authentication

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly app the uses Azure ADB2C for authentication via MSAL. Staring form the default project template most things work as expected (login, logout).

Single Sign On (SSO) kinda works. If I am already logged in with Azure and I go to a page that requires authentication the app will authenticate the user and correctly identify that the user is already logged in and show the page and the user will show as being logged in.

However, if the user start off on the app landing/home page which does not require authentication, no authentication is attempted and therefore the user does not get logged in.

We have an companion Xamarin app the authenticates to the same Azure ADB2C instance and it uses a silent authentication process to automatically log the user in if they are already authenticated.

That is the experience I want but can't figure out how to do that in Blazor WebAssembly.

I read about using possibly using an MSAL.js library ([MSAL with Azure AD B2C and Single Sign On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242142/msal-with-azure-ad-b2c-and-single-sign-on)) but I can't find good docs on how to do it with standard Blazor WebAssembly.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: https://code-maze.com/azure-active-directory-b2c-with-blazor-webassembly-hosted-apps/

Comment: Thanks adeel41 but that article is just about basic Blazor WebAssembly and Azure ADB2C and does not say anything I could find about silent-login.